# “Smart” switches buzz, and breaker panel buzz

Tags: electrical

I installed 2 smart switches. They are wired back to the panel with an existing 3 conductor 14 (two hots one shared neutral, as per my previous question. The switches buzz slightly, apparently a common thing. But when both light switches are on the breakers in the panel buzz. A slight hardly noticeable, but I hear it. Is this an issue!

Comment: Would turn off breakers then post pictures of breakers and how you wired your switches, in your question.

Comment: Are these UL listed smart switches?

Comment: Yeah, that ain't right.  Buzzing at the switch might be attributed to the switch, but buzzing at the breaker means *both* buzzes are due to a wiring fault.  What make is your panel? What make are the breakers?

Comment: What make and model are the breakers/panel, and the smart switches for that matter?

Comment: The panel is. Square D QO panel with square d 15 amp breakers. The switches are 2 cooper halo switches I got from a neighbour who bought lights that came with the switches. I’m currently away working for a week. So I don’t have pics. So it only buzzes at the panel when both switches are on. I think I’ll ditch the smart switches and see what happens.

Comment: The switches are HIWAC1BLE40AWH

Comment: @AngusMcintyre -- are they *switches*, or dimmers of some sort, and do the breakers that buzz have TEST buttons on them?

Comment: Smart switches with dimmers. No test button on the breakers.

Comment: I have an electrician buddy, who’s going to look at it.

Comment: So my buddy removed the one smart switch and replaced with a normal single switch and no hum/buzz at the panel. So either the one switch is crap, or they don’t like the shared neutral?

Answer (score 0):

I can't know for sure if this is the issue because I'm not there, but I personally have experienced buzzing from a panel caused by corrosion on the bus bars that feed the breakers to the point that they destroy themselves at the back side. I used a plastic and rubberized handled, small brass wire brush to scrub them clean and replaced the damaged breakers and haven't had a problem since.

I don't recommend you remove the breakers and certainly don't touch the bus bars at the back with ANYTHING unless you know what you're doing! Electricity kills. A licensed electrician would probably replace the panel in my mentioned case in particular, but I'm not made of money, so I did it the cheap-arse way.

The buzzing inside the "smart switch" on the other hand is likely coming from the internal relay's coil. The coil is much like a speaker coil, and plays the note that's being sent into it: 60Hz sinewave. This coil is what magnetically pulls the switch contacts together to allow current to flow to your device. There's also a power supply inside to drive the microcontroller unit inside that might be the cause.